# Why was the Tulsa Port placed at Catoosa?

Tags: united-states, rivers

I was looking at various maps of Oklahoma, and the question came to me of
why does the Tulsa Port of Catoosa even exist.

Tulsa lies on the Arkansas River, which is considerably larger than the Verdigris River on which the Tulsa Port of Catoosa lies. Also Tulsa was a vastly larger city than Catoosa (by about 2 orders of magnitude before Catoosa began growing after the port was placed there). Wouldn't it be more efficient to transport goods directly from/to Tulsa via the Arkansas River than to move goods from Tulsa to Catoosa to then be transported via the Verdigris River, which in fact is a tributary of the Arkansas and flows into the Arkansas anyway? This seems like a pointless diversion of goods that makes the entire transportation process longer and more inefficient.

**Why was the decision made in the 1960s to develop a port in Catoosa on the Verdigris River instead of developing the banks of Tulsa that lie directly on the Arkansas River?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because going up the Arkansas river is steeper than going up the Verdigris River. Tulsa has an elevation of 722 ft above sea level, vs 623 ft for Catoosa. For technical and engineering reasons, Catoosa was the more economical terminus.

Originally, the Arkansas River was not naturally suited for navigation, at least not year round. The Army Corps of Engineers spent the better part of the 1960s changing this by constructing the [McClellan–Kerr Arkansas River Navigation System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McClellan%E2%80%93Kerr_Arkansas_River_Navigation_System). During the planning for this project, it became obvious that departing the Arkansas at its confluence with the Verdigris would be the more feasible route.

This is revealed from Congressional records:

> "If the reach of the Arkansas River between the mouth of the Grand River and Tulsa is included . . . 18 locks and dams will be required. If the alternate route is used by way of the Verdigris River to Catoosa, Okla., 5 locks and dams (1 on the Arksansas and 4 on the Verdigris) will be required. The estimated first cost of the locks and dams by the Tulsa route is $72,000,000; and by the Catoosa route it is $12,500,000 . . . From the above estimates of cost it is evident that the more economical route is to Catoosa as a terminus instead of to Tulsa.
>
> <sub>*Arkansas River and Tributaries*, 74th Congress, 1st Session, House Document 308</sub>

Comment: lol. Thanks for fielding this one for my on a day I'm under the weather. And I was actually a little curious about the details myself, even though I grew up hearing how Catoosa was the furthest navigable point.